# Is it possible to run mock inside an lxc container with libvirt?

Tags: mocking, lxc, libvirt, mknod

[mock](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Mock) is used to build rpms.  I wish to use it inside an lxc container, managed by libvirt, however libvirt configures lxc to block `mknod(2)` calls, which mock uses to build its chroot.

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the capability was added in a recent version.

`<capabilities policy='default'>
      <mknod state='on'/>
      <sys_chroot state='on'/>
    </capabilities>`